# Co-ordinate Geometry

Tags: polar-coordinates

What is the point of intersection of perpendicular bisector and angle bisector of a triangle called?

Here's the question:
In a triangle *ABC*, perpendicular bisector of side *AC* is $x-y=4$ and angle bisector of *A* is $3x+4y+k=0$. Vertex *C* is the incenter of triangle formed by $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$. Find equation of *AB*?

Comment: It is likely one of those on this comprehensive (?) list: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/TriangleCenters.html Also there is this http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheIntersectionOfAnAngleBisectorAndAPerpendicularBisector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite a long process of finding the points of intersections.
The first is to find the coordinate of the incenter which can be found out from:

$(Ox,Oy)=(\frac{aAx+bBx+cCx}{p},\frac{aAy+bBy+cCy}{p})$

with $p= perimeter$
$;a,b,c=side$ $lengths$ $opposite$ $to$  $A(Ax,Ay),B(Bx,By),C(Cx,Cy)$

$(Ox,Oy)=(1,1)$ for the given problem, which is the coordinate of the vertex $C$.

The equation of the line perpendicular to $x-y=4$ and passes through the point $(1,1)$ is $y+x=2$.

Therefore, the mirror of the point $(1,1)$ through the line $y-x=4$ is $(5,-3)$.

But, $3x+4y+k=0$ passes through the point $(5,-3)$ and solving  gives $k=-3$.

As Line $3x+4y-3=0$ is the anglebisector , we can use the mirror concept using this line as the mirror and find out the equation of line $AB$ i.e the line that passes through $(5,-3)$ and the mirror of $(1,1)$ through the line $3x+4y-3=0$ as the mirror, and the mirror point is $(p,q)=(\frac{1}{25},\frac{-7}{25})$.

Therefore, the line through $(5,-3)$ and $(\frac{1}{25},\frac{-7}{25})$ will be the equation of the line $AB$

Comment: I get $(p,q)=\left(\frac{1}{25},-\frac{7}{25}\right)$. please check

Comment: Thanks. I did the calculations in a hurry.